# What went wrong with my calculation of Precision and Recall?

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification, precision-recall

[image: confusion matrix]

Suppose there are 8 red balls, 1 green, and 1 blue. Very imbalanced data. I'm stupid and predict all of 10 are red. Did I get the **confusion matrix** correct? If so, I sum over all categories the true positives, and I sum over all (true positive + false positive), their quotient should be the **precision** of my stupid classification, right? Why does it look so good? Same thing to the **recall**.

Also, they don't agree with the results computed by `sklearn`, which seem much more sensible.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score

a = ["R"]*8 + ["G"] + ["B"]
b = ["R"]*10

print("Precision:", precision_score(a,b,average="macro"))
print("Recall:", recall_score(a,b,average="macro"))
```

```
Precision: 0.26666666666666666
Recall: 0.3333333333333333
```